# DOUBLE gets returned as BLOB

Tags: mysql, typing

I am having some confusion with my SELECT:

```
SELECT  
    mergedData.rawValue,
    mergedData.validatedValue,
    IFNULL(mergedData.validatedValue, mergedData.rawValue) as mergedValue
FROM
    [...]
```

While `mergedData.rawValue` and `mergedData.validatedValue` return as DOUBLE, the `IFNULL` statement returns a BLOB. Why is that happening? And how can I make it return a DOUBLE instead?

EDIT:
I am merging two tables that have exactly the same structure in my Select by emulating a `FULL JOIN`. The data is stored as a DOUBLE in both tables:

TableRawData (NOX gets loaded into mergedData.rawValue):

```
timed (BIGINT(20)) --- NOX (DOUBLE)
1380583800000          8.972167
```

TableValidatedData (NOX gets loaded into mergedData.validatedValue):

```
timed (BIGINT(20)) --- NOX (DOUBLE)
1380583800000          9.506166
```

EDIT2: My full SELECT:

```
SET @StartTime  = 1356998400000;
SET @EndTime    = 1386546000000;

SELECT  
    mergedData.rawValue,
    mergedData.validatedValue,
    CAST(IFNULL(mergedData.validatedValue, mergedData.rawValue) AS DECIMAL(10, 5)) as mergedValue
FROM
 (SELECT 
        Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as months,
            Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as years,
            DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as days,
            HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as hours,
            MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as minutes,
            IF(true, avg(NOX), null) as rawValue,
            FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000) as timeValue,
            IF(true, 1, 0) as IsValid,
            NULL as validatedValue
    FROM
        nabelnrt_bas
    WHERE
        timed > @StartTime
            AND timed < @EndTime
    GROUP BY concat(years, months, days) UNION (
 SELECT 
        Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as months,
            Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as years,
            DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as days,
            HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as hours,
            MINUTE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000)) as minutes,
            IF(true, avg(NOX), null) as validatedValue,
            FROM_UNIXTIME(timed / 1000) as timeValue,
            IF(true, 1, 0) as IsValid,
            NULL as rawValue
    FROM
        nabelvalidated_bas
    WHERE
        timed > @StartTime
            AND timed < @EndTime
    GROUP BY concat(years, months, days))) as mergedData
```

Comment: Please, show your table structure

Comment: I don't know what your data means and where it comes from, but if both tables describe practically the same data (as it seems), why don't you use a `NOX_raw` and `NOX_validated DEFAULT NULL` (still my answer below would be applicable). That would save you the pain of merging a table.

Comment: @AmazingDreams I am loading data from a sensor that measures NOX (NO2 + NO) concentration in the air. The validation needs some time therefor the raw data is available much earlier. This is why I am combining these two tables to load all available data while prioritizing the validated data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast it

```
SELECT  
    mergedData.rawValue,
    mergedData.validatedValue,
    CAST(IFNULL(mergedData.validatedValue, mergedData.rawValue) AS DECIMAL[(M[,D])]) as mergedValue
FROM
```

Please note the `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]` you should fill it as your table is defined.

Edit, [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) might also be interesting. Example usage;

```
SELECT  
    mergedData.rawValue,
    mergedData.validatedValue,
    COALESCE(mergedData.validatedValue, mergedData.rawValue) as mergedValue
FROM
```

Perheps you would not need to cast it then

Comment: COALESCE did not work, still gets returned as BLOB. However the cast to decimals works great! :)

Comment: However I still don't understand why it got returned as BLOB in the first place.

Comment: It seems that MySQL is not sure what datatype will get out of the `IFNULL` function. How is `mergedTable` created?

Comment: Added my full select to my question

Comment: I think that `IF(true, avg(NOX), null) as rawValue,` and `IF(true, avg(NOX), null) as validatedValue,` will return either a `NULL` or a `DOUBLE`/`DECIMAL` value, which must fit into the same column. MySQL seems to choose a `BLOB` for this and even though it might not be the best choice, I think it's fine the way it is now. Sidenote; I'd remove all the time conversions as you don't use it in your final `SELECT` statement.

Comment: No, the strange thing is, that `mergedData.rawValue` and `mergedData.validatedValue` output as DOUBLE (I have them in the top-level select to check their types). So it really has to do something with the `IFNULL`